# Convert grammar to LL(1)

Tags: grammar, ll-grammar

Got a simple grammar that have to transform to `LL(1)` i've tried many solutions but removed the left recursion but it does not produce the same grammar.

The grammar is this:

```
X -> E $
E -> E E o
E -> n
```

Any idea how can i turn this right recursive? Is there any general algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing left recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652060/removing-left-recursion)

Comment: If the indicated duplicate isn't good enough, there are dozens of other similar questions. Or look at the Wikipedia article.